# How to stop FireFox "Refresh now for the changes to take effect" "Refresh now" "Refresh later" popup?

Tags: firefox, popups, refresh

My system:
Win10 Home Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134
Firefox 66.0.2
Dell XPS 13 9370 laptop
16gb RAM

This is also happening in my Mac and Win7Pro pc's.

I typically have 10-15 tabs open.

A tab can sit there for quite some time, or, I can just have opened it 
when this pops up across the top of the page in a banner (The screenshot will appear in the middle of the page of another tab.  This popup is under the bookmarks toolbar):

[image]

> Refresh now for the changes to take effect <kbd>Refresh now</kbd> <kbd>Refresh later</kbd>

How to turn this off?

Comment: Does this still happen?

Comment: Yes, and now on FF version 70.

Comment: I'd recommend making a fresh profile to test whether this is an issue specific to your configuration. 
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles

Comment: It was an extension: Dr.Web Link Checker.  Turned it off, request immediately went away.  Turned it back on, request immediately came back on.

Comment: Better late than never!